# React component doesn't update after redux dispatch

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select, redux

I have a react Select that changes its value. I want to send an API call to change its value in DB on the change event. Here I have the HTML and JS in the react component:

```
const findStatus = (searchedStatus, statusOptions) => {
        if (searchedStatus) {
            for (let j = 0; j < statusOptions.length; j++) {
                if (statusOptions[j].value === searchedStatus) {
                    return statusOptions[j]
                }
            }
        }
        return statusOptions[0]
    }

    const changeStatus = async (currentStatus, id) => {
        const newStatus = currentStatus.value
        let action = await patchReview({token, username, newStatus, id})  
        dispatch(action)
    } 

<Select
  name="statuses" 
  options={statusOptions}  
  value={findStatus(review.reviewStatus, statusOptions)}
  onChange={(e) => {changeStatus(e, review.id)}}  />
```

The service does the API call like that:

```
export async function patchReview(params, callback) {
  const encodedStr = params.username + ':' + params.token;
  const endpointURL = HOST.local_api + endpoint.patchReview + '/' + params.id
  let request = new Request(endpointURL, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers : {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(encodedStr)
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "status": params.newStatus
    })

  });

  let response = await fetch(request)

  let action = {
    'type': Types.UPDATE_REVIEW,
    'payload': await response.json()
  } 

  return action
}
```

After that I dispatch the action like this:

```
    case Types.UPDATE_REVIEW:
      return {
        ...state,
        reviews: state.reviews.map(review => {
            if (review.id === action.payload.id) {
              return action.payload
            }
            return review
        })
      }
```

But the value of the Select gets updated only after refreshing the page and I don't understand why. The API call returns a new review that replaces the old one.

Comment: How do you get that `review` variable in your component?

Comment: I take all reviews with api call in a parent component and I pass the review as prop in this component.

Comment: How do *those* get it out of the store?